# Show that $X = L^p \cap L^q$ with norm $||f|| = ||f||_p + ||f||_q$ is a Banach space.

Tags: measure-theory, normed-spaces, lebesgue-integral

I have difficulties understanding the solution of the following problem: ($L^p$ denotes $L^p(\mathbb{R})$)

Let $1 \le p \lt q\lt \infty$.

Show that $X = L^p \cap L^q$ with norm $||f|| = ||f||_p + ||f||_q$ is a Banach space.

That it is a normed space is clear to already. It is the completeness part that I'm not sure about.

Let $f_k$ be Cauchy in $X$. That implies that $f_k$ is Cauchy in both $L^p$ and $L^q$. Since they are complete, $\exists h \in L^p$ and $g\in L^q$ such that $||h - f_k||_p \to 0$ and $||g - f_k||_q \to 0$.

The goal is to show that $h = g$, hence $X$ is Banach.

Since convergence in $L^p$ implies convergence in measure, and convergence in measure implies that the existence of a subsequence that converges a.e., we get that $\exists f_{n_k}$ and $f_{l_k}$ such that
$$f_{n_k} \to g \ \text{  a.e.}$$
and
$$f_{l_k} \to h \ \text{ a.e.}$$

Now comes the part I'm not sure about. In the solution I have, they claim that:

1: $g=h$ a.e.  (why?)

2: Hence, $g$ and $h$ belong to the same equivalence class. (why?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking $(n_k)$ and $(l_k)$ does not lead to $g=h$ a.e. The argument needs a slight modification.

You have to first choose $(n_k)$ with $f_{n_k} \to g$ a.e. and note that $\|f_{n_k}-h\|_p \to 0$. So there is  a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_j}})$ which converges to $h$ a.e. Now $(f_{n_{k_j}})$  converges to both $g$ and $h$ a.e. which implies $g=h$ a.e.

If two functions are equal a.e they both belong to the same equivalence class. That is by definition of equivalence class of measuarble functions.

Answer (score 1):

Following your notation, $h$ denotes the limit in the $L^p$ norm and $g$ denotes the one in the $L^q$ norm. You have established that there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ such that $f_{n_k}$ converges a.e. to $g$. To conclude you just need to use Fatou's lemma:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g-h|^p d\mu\leq\liminf_{k\to+\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|h-f_{n_k}|^pd\mu = 0,$$
which means $g=h$ a.e.